# Why Doesn't Copied Array Equal Original Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming, slice

I've been learning more about functional programming and the idea of keeping functions pure.  So I experimented with taking an array and making a copy of it with the *slice* function like so...

```
var text = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
copy = text.slice(0);
```

I have two arrays at this point of the same type and with the same values but when I test to see if they're the same...

```
text === copy; => returns 'false'
```

Why isn't the copy seen as the same array by Javascript?

Comment: Because in JS object equality means that both are the _same_ object. If they have the same content, but are different objects, then they are treated as being different.

Comment: That's the point, two different arrays are **never** the same, even if they contain the same values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Ahh...that makes sense!  Thanks for helping clear that up!